# How many 4 digit numbers are there whose decimal notation contains not more than two digits?

Tags: combinatorics

How many 4 digit numbers are there whose decimal notation contains not more than two digits?
Answer is 576. 
The question is very confusing.
This is Arun Sharma CAT question.

Answer (score 1):

Just count them. Let's suppose you can have digits $a$ and $b$, $a\ne b$. Then the possible combinations are$$aaaa \ \ 9\\abaa\ 81\\aaba\ 81\\aaab\ 81\\abba\ 81\\abab\ 81\\aabb\ 81\\abbb\ 81$$
In total you have then $81\cdot7+9=576$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the four patterns $AAA*,AAB*,AB**$. The number of choices is therefore

$9\times 1\times 1\times 10+ 9\times 1\times 9\times2 +9\times 9\times 2\times 2=576.$

Comment: what if all four numbers of AAAA? I couldnt understand please explain me again if possible

Comment: The AAA* includes this case. There are $9$ choices for $A$ and then $10$ choices for the final digit (one of which is $A$,)